# Part of an SQL query is not executing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

The update statement of the following SQL statement is not working.

After execution it says:

```
Query performed correctly: 0 row(s) affected.
```

The timescount column should be incremented by 1 after each call, but it is not happening. I need your expert eyes to scrutinize the statement. I have also shown my database schema below the code.

```
require '15_12.php';

//Now, let us create an instance of mydb.
$mydb = new mydb ("localhost","root","");

//Select a database to use.
$mydb->selectdb ("myquotes");

//Then, let's try to return a row set.
$adata = $mydb->getrows ("SELECT url_string FROM tshirt WHERE timescount = 0 ORDER BY url_id ASC LIMIT 3");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count ($adata); $i++){

        $result = PIPHP_GetLinksFromURL($adata[$i]);
        echo "<ul>";
        for ($j = 0 ; $j < count($result) ; ++$j) {
        echo "<li>$result[$j]</li>";
        }

        //Now, hold the row in a variable
        $url_escaped = $adata[$i];

        //Now, let's perform an action.
        $mydb->execute ("UPDATE tshirt SET timescount=timescount+1 WHERE url_string='url_escaped'");



    }
```

Database structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tshirt` (
  `url_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url_string` varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
  `timescount` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`url_id`)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `$` in your variable which causes it to be used as a string literal:

```
$mydb->execute ("UPDATE tshirt SET timescount=timescount+1 WHERE url_string='url_escaped'");
                                                                           ^^^^
                                                                           HERE
```

should be

```
$mydb->execute ("UPDATE tshirt SET timescount=timescount+1 WHERE url_string='$url_escaped'");
```

Comment: Oh, yes, I missed it. Thank you for your time and statement.

Comment: Given the OP's history (`dot`-`dot`-`dot`)